# Google Vision API CameraSourcePreview FPS

Tags: android, android-camera, frame-rate, face-recognition, google-vision

I am trying to develop android face recognition app. Starting from [Google Vision API FaceTracker example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker) - **how can I get camera preview FPS value**?

I understand that I can set requested FPS on `CameraSource.Builder()` with `setRequestedFps()`, but I want **actual** FPS value updated every second or every new frame. Is it possible to get or calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to calculate the FPS is by adding this logic to the [GraphicFaceTracker](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L280) class. Notet that the callbacks [onNewItem()](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L293), [onMissing()](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L312) and [onUpdate()](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/FaceTracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/facetracker/FaceTrackerActivity.java#L301) may be invoked on the same frame, so your calculation should account for multple callbacks at (almost) the same time.

This calculation will not reveal the underlying camera frame rate, but rather the detector rate. If you need the camera rate, you can ***a)*** trust whatever you [requested](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/CameraSource.Builder.html#setRequestedFps(float)) or ***b)*** rewrite or override the [CameraSource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java) class.